# Spinner populate with SQLite dependent with another Spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

I have 3 spinners on my application and I have to populate each spinner with data from my DB (SQLite) on Android Studio.

Here is the rendering of the application:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43W02.png)

My first spinner (Commune, in english : City) is populated with my DB

**My problem :**

To populate my second spinner, I want to include data from my database dependent on the choice of my first spinner.

How to return the value of my first spinner to query my DB for the values of my second spinner ?

***Code :***

> /** Function to load the spinner data from SQLite database */

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    BddCeos db = new BddCeos(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> labelsCommune = db.getAllCommune();
    List<String> labelsPoste = db.getAllPoste();
    List<String> labelsRef = db.getAllRef();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCommune = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelsCommune);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterPoste = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelsPoste);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterRef = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelsRef);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner_input_commune.setAdapter(dataAdapterCommune);
    spinner_input_nom_poste.setAdapter(dataAdapterPoste);
    spinner_input_ref_wapiti.setAdapter(dataAdapterRef);

}



@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    // On selecting a spinner item
    String Labels = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Vous avez sélectionné : " + Labels, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution by myself :**

```
spinner_input_commune.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                BddCeos db = new BddCeos(getApplicationContext());

                List<String> labelsPoste = db.getFindPosteByCommune(spinner_input_commune.getSelectedItem().toString());
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterPoste = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Formulaire.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelsPoste);
                spinner_input_nom_poste.setAdapter(dataAdapterPoste);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            }

        });

spinner_input_nom_poste.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                BddCeos db = new BddCeos(getApplicationContext());

                List<String> labelsRef = db.getFindRefWapitiByPost(spinner_input_nom_poste.getSelectedItem().toString());
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterRef = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Formulaire.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelsRef);
                spinner_input_ref_wapiti.setAdapter(dataAdapterRef);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            }

        });
```